# get specific row and column using maatwebite excel

Tags: arrays, excel, laravel

I am new in laravel and maatwebsite excel. I need to import excel to database
but I need only specific row and column to import.

how to do that in laravel? please help I googling for this method for days and have no luck.

Thanks a alot for your help.

Dian.

this is my dd() from excel reader :

```
RowCollection {#105908 ▼
  #heading: array:28 [▶]
  #title: "Sheet1"
  #items: array:18 [▶]
}
```

this is my detail, in row 2 i only need column 6 and  10

```
RowCollection {#105908 ▼
  #heading: array:28 [▶]
  #title: "Sheet1"
  #items: array:18 [▼
    0 => CellCollection {#105905 ▼
      #title: null
      #items: array:22 [▶]
    }
    1 => CellCollection {#105323 ▶}
    2 => CellCollection {#105317 ▼
      #title: null
      #items: array:22 [▼
        0 => null
        1 => null
        2 => null
        3 => null
        4 => "Prinsipal"
        5 => null
        6 => "company name"
        7 => null
        8 => "in ctn"
        9 => "Customer:"
        10 => "customer Name"
        11 => null
        12 => null
        13 => null
        14 => null
        15 => null
        16 => null
        17 => null
        18 => null
        19 => null
        20 => null
        21 => null
      ]
    }
    3 => CellCollection {#532 ▶}
    4 => CellCollection {#105286 ▶}
    5 => CellCollection {#105261 ▶}
    6 => CellCollection {#105239 ▶}
    7 => CellCollection {#105210 ▶}
    8 => CellCollection {#105186 ▶}
    9 => CellCollection {#105183 ▶}
    10 => CellCollection {#105160 ▶}
    11 => CellCollection {#105157 ▶}
    12 => CellCollection {#105134 ▶}
    13 => CellCollection {#105131 ▶}
    14 => CellCollection {#105107 ▶}
    15 => CellCollection {#105077 ▶}
    16 => CellCollection {#105082 ▶}
    17 => CellCollection {#105079 ▶}
  ]
}
```

this is my detail, in row 7 I need column 15  until 18 to get date

```
RowCollection {#105908 ▼
  #heading: array:28 [▶]
  #title: "Sheet1"
  #items: array:18 [▼
    0 => CellCollection {#105905 ▼
      #title: null
      #items: array:22 [▶]
    }
    1 => CellCollection {#105323 ▶}
    2 => CellCollection {#105317 ▶}
    3 => CellCollection {#532 ▶}
    4 => CellCollection {#105286 ▶}
    5 => CellCollection {#105261 ▶}
    6 => CellCollection {#105239 ▶}
    7 => CellCollection {#105210 ▼
      #title: null
      #items: array:22 [▼
        0 => null
        1 => null
        2 => null
        3 => null
        4 => null
        5 => "A"
        6 => "B"
        7 => "C=(A+B)"
        8 => "D"
        9 => "E=(C-D)"
        10 => "F"
        11 => "G"
        12 => null
        13 => null
        14 => "H=(F+G)-E"
        15 => Carbon {#105209 ▼
          +"date": "2017-05-05 00:00:00.000000"
          +"timezone_type": 3
          +"timezone": "UTC"
        }
        16 => Carbon {#105156 ▶}
        17 => Carbon {#105182 ▶}
        18 => Carbon {#105187 ▶}
        19 => "Total"
        20 => null
        21 => null
      ]
    }
    8 => CellCollection {#105186 ▶}
    9 => CellCollection {#105183 ▶}
    10 => CellCollection {#105160 ▶}
    11 => CellCollection {#105157 ▶}
    12 => CellCollection {#105134 ▶}
    13 => CellCollection {#105131 ▶}
    14 => CellCollection {#105107 ▶}
    15 => CellCollection {#105077 ▶}
    16 => CellCollection {#105082 ▶}
    17 => CellCollection {#105079 ▶}
  ]
}
```

and lastly for detail I need data start from row 8 To last row - 1

```
RowCollection {#105908 ▼
  #heading: array:28 [▶]
  #title: "Sheet1"
  #items: array:18 [▼
    0 => CellCollection {#105905 ▼
      #title: null
      #items: array:22 [▶]
    }
    1 => CellCollection {#105323 ▶}
    2 => CellCollection {#105317 ▶}
    3 => CellCollection {#532 ▶}
    4 => CellCollection {#105286 ▶}
    5 => CellCollection {#105261 ▶}
    6 => CellCollection {#105239 ▶}
    7 => CellCollection {#105210 ▶}
    8 => CellCollection {#105186 ▼
      #title: null
      #items: array:22 [▼
        0 => null
        1 => "Prod X"
        2 => "Product X"
        3 => "Carton"
        4 => null
        5 => null
        6 => 0.0
        7 => 0.0
        8 => null
        9 => 0.0
        10 => null
        11 => null
        12 => 0.0
        13 => null
        14 => 0.0
        15 => 300.0
        16 => 300.0
        17 => 300.0
        18 => 300.0
        19 => 1200.0
        20 => 0.0
        21 => 0.0
      ]
    }
    9 => CellCollection {#105183 ▶}
    10 => CellCollection {#105160 ▶}
    11 => CellCollection {#105157 ▶}
    12 => CellCollection {#105134 ▶}
    13 => CellCollection {#105131 ▶}
    14 => CellCollection {#105107 ▶}
    15 => CellCollection {#105077 ▶}
    16 => CellCollection {#105082 ▶}
    17 => CellCollection {#105079 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Comment: maybe this approach you to right solution, http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import#chunk

Comment: you can get all CellCollection and simply map/filter/chunk it, as you wish for

Comment: thanks Odin. I'll Try it.